# Prevent Publish to SCP Repository from Maintaining Original Folder Structure

Tags: jenkins

I'm running Jenkins v1.581 and Publish artifacts to SCP Repository v1.8.
I am able to successfully copy my artifacts over SCP to a destination directory; so I know that server names, authentication, etc... are all correct.

My configuration looks something like this:

Source: tmp/distribution/target/deploy/opt/**
Destination: opt

When Jenkins `puts` the file over SCP it ends up in a directory structure of `opt/tmp/distribution/target/deploy/opt/rest_of_path`.  It looks like it's keeping the original path of the file as it existed as an artifact and appending it to the destination path.  This causes my artifacts to be deployed to an unexpected path.

My expectation is that they would end up as `opt/rest_of_path`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the Publish to SCP Repository with the Send build artifacts over SSH plugin.  This plugin has an option for `Remove prefix` which does exactly what I wanted.